# How do display hardware contrast settings affect color contrast?

Tags: contrast

I have been interested in finding the results for this, but I have yet to find a reliable source for the following:

Given that hex color #FF0000 might look more like #FF3333 on a screen with a higher default level of  brightness, is their a 'range of screen defaults' measuring the relative range of brightness and contrast?

I know about the 'WCAG 2.0's requirements for colour contrast', but this primarily focuses on some arbitrary measurement of human vision degradation over time + the visually handicapped. I am specifically looking for something that comes from the perspective of the hardware generating a different color due to it's default setting and range.

P.S. There are not nearly enough tags to describe this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time it is based on the user's preferences. A lot of software, systems, etc try to help the user optimize their brightness and contrast settings through various means. Often you will see configuration tools like this one in Windows 8:

[image: Windows 8 Calibration]

There are so many factors at play here that unless you have hardware level capabilities there isn't much you would be able to change. But like the Windows example you are capable of educating the user and help the user adjust their settings. While Windows actually adjusts the image it sends back to your monitors, you will have to resort to educating the user to set this themselves.

I do not believe there is an actual range in which you can reasonably expect every screen to have. My home's desktop monitors are different from my laptops and also vastly different from my work ones. I try to calibrate them often to keep them in tune but even then I cannot get them to be the same.  It makes it frustrating for me who tries to understand what the users will see.

Comment: Having users adjust their screen settings is a standard practice, but I guess that is the easiest known solution out there for now.